# Make spider in scrapy faster without scrapyd

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy spider in a linux server that scrapes 4827 links, and from each link extracts 8 html tags(title, date, description, etc.). Currently I am using the default settings and the total amount of time that is required for extracting the data is 18 minutes. I am wondering if there is a way to make it faster without using scrapyd. Above is the code I have written.

scraper

```
from pathlib import Path

import scrapy

from siftlink_scraper.items import SiftlinkScraperItem

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

class GooglePatentsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google_patents'
    allowed_domains = ['patents.google.com']

    with open(BASE_DIR.joinpath('spiders/url_patents.txt'), "rt") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = SiftlinkScraperItem()
        
        item['publication_number'] = response.xpath('//dd[@itemprop="publicationNumber"]/text()').get() 
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="title"]/text()').get() 
        item['abstract'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="description"]/@content').get()
        item['claims'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="claim-text"]/text()').getall() 
        item['applicant'] = response.xpath('//dd[@itemprop="assigneeCurrent"]/text()').get() 
        item['publication_date'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="DC.date"]/@content')[1].get()    
        item['application_date'] = response.xpath('//meta[@name="DC.date"]/@content')[0].get() 
        item['status'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="status"]/text()').get()     

        yield item
        
    def close(self, reason):
        start_time = self.crawler.stats.get_value('start_time')
        finish_time = self.crawler.stats.get_value('finish_time')
        print("Total run time: ", finish_time-start_time)
```

settings

```
# Scrapy settings for siftlink_scraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'siftlink_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['siftlink_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'siftlink_scraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'siftlink_scraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'siftlink_scraper.middlewares.SiftlinkScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'siftlink_scraper.middlewares.SiftlinkScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'siftlink_scraper.pipelines.SiftlinkScraperPipeline': 300,
}

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
#MONGO_URI = 'mongodb+srv://christos:5669/mito@cluster0.rx7oj.mongodb.net/googlePatentsDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
MONGO_DATABASE = 'testDB'

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Comment: These two configurations can increase the speed, but pay attention to the limitations `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`，`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`

Comment: If your number of links is fixed, consider batching multiple spiders to grab at the same time (Split the link into multiple parts).

Comment: Do you mean to write, for example two spiders and split the urls in half and run the spiders from two different terminals?

Comment: yes, It is a way to increase speed.